# How to find Dwr session check example and site?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, dwr

good day.

I Recently study dwr.

But... I don't find session check example..

plz recommand dwr session check example and site..

thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this page](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/server/javaapi.html) You can include servlet objects in parameters list of Your remoted method object. From this point You check session and so.